# implementing sqlite sort by function and select function together in python along with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am writing a program to search through a database. My table contains Id, Title, Date, Content. I only need date and content as output. The output must be sorted with respect to 'Id'. But I don't want Id in output. How can I implement this ?
I tried to sort data before selecting Id and Content, unfortunately it is not giving me desired result.

```
import os
import pandas as pd

conn = sqlite3.connect('insight.db')
c = conn.cursor()

def search_keyword(term):
    c.execute("SELECT * FROM GkData ORDER BY Id DESC")
    print(pd.read_sql_query("SELECT date, content FROM GkData WHERE {} LIKE '%{}%'".format('content', term), conn))
    c.execute("SELECT content FROM GkData WHERE {} LIKE '%{}%'".format('content', term))
    data = c.fetchall()
    for idx, row in enumerate(data):
        new_data = str(row).replace("',)", "  ").replace("('", " ")
        print('[ ' + str(idx) + ' ] =====> ' + new_data)

while True:
    search = input("Search term: ")
    search_keyword(str(search))

conn.close()
```

[Output image of the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9no0F.png)

[Image of Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfIn5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The output must be sorted with respect to 'Id'. But I don't want Id in output. How can I implement this ?"

```
SELECT date, content FROM GkData WHERE content LIKE %something% ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: @ balderman ```SELECT date, content FROM GkData ORDER BY id ASC WHERE content LIKE %new%``` is not working. I need to combine sorting and search. If i do sorting alone it is working.

Comment: see the code change - the ORDER BY is after the WHERE